# Error during assets:precompile because of Javascript function default argument

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rake

I use Rails 4.0.0,
    I do rake assets:precompile 
on ENV - production, and have some error message:

```
rake aborted!
Unexpected token operator «=», expected punc «,» (line: 15816, col: 39, pos: 465171)
Error
at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20130828-23982-1kgxmyu.js:2357:10736)
at js_error (/tmp/execjs20130828-23982-1kgxmyu.js:2357:10955)
at croak (/tmp/execjs20130828-23982-1kgxmyu.js:2357:18665)
at token_error (/tmp/execjs20130828-23982-1kgxmyu.js:2357:18802)
at expect_token (/tmp/execjs20130828-23982-1kgxmyu.js:2357:19025)
at expect (/tmp/execjs20130828-23982-1kgxmyu.js:2357:19163)
at /tmp/execjs20130828-23982-1kgxmyu.js:2357:23402
at /tmp/execjs20130828-23982-1kgxmyu.js:2357:23466
at /tmp/execjs20130828-23982-1kgxmyu.js:2357:20786
at /tmp/execjs20130828-23982-1kgxmyu.js:2357:19536
(in ~/RubymineProjects/Hermes/app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb)        ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib    /execjs/external_runtime.rb:68:in `extract_result'
```

This construction raises error: function searchHelper(myMap,coords,**cond=false**)
But without default argument command finish without exit code: function searchHelper(myMap,coords,**cond**)

What Is it? Where can I read about it?

Answer (score 5):

If anyone else runs into this problem, you might have set a default value for an function argument, which is not possible in an javascript code.

**INVALID**

```
function hello(param = true){
  ...
}
```

**VALID**

```
function hello(param) {
  if (typeof param == 'undefined')
    param = true;

  ...
}
```

Comment: Very helpful - this is exactly what I did

Answer (score 1):

I know this was answered quite a few years ago, but I have been working with a Rails application in version 3.2 and recently ran into this problem. I want to add to [Tomáš Dundáček's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21598142/10181001). It turns out that default parameters in Javascript in the following format:

```js
function hello(param = true) {
    ...
}
```

is an ES6 syntax feature, and is not available in ES5. Like what was mentioned above,

```js
function hello(param) {
    if (typeof param == 'undefined')
        param = true;
    // or
    param = param || true;

    ...
}
```

is valid in ES5. Depending on what JavaScript libraries you use during pre-compilation (uglify-js for instance), your JavaScript files may not compile properly. If the libraries only understand ES5, including any ES6 features will cause this and similar errors during pre-compilation. This issue discussed more in [this thread on Github](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails/issues/137).